# rsync: How to exclude Dotfiles only in topmost directory?

Tags: regex, bash, rsync

When performing backups under Bash with `rsync`, I'm trying to exclude all dotfiles and hidden directories in the top directory, but **not** those in otherwise targeted directories. For example:

```
/copyme.c  
/.dontcopythisfile  
/.dontcopythisdirectory/or_its_contents  
/directory/.butcopymetoo
```

`rsync -a --include=".includeme" --exclude=".*" . DEST` fails to copy the desired dotfiles in subdirectories, but variations such as `--exclude="./.*"` also fail.

Suggestions? Does this require a filter rule as opposed to the simpler `--exclude`?

Answer (score 13):

You should use anchor, and in rsync the anchor character is '/'.

So in your string should be:

```
rsync -a --include="/.includeme" --exclude="/.*" ./ DEST
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer to create .rsync-filter files containing the patterns:

```
- /.*
```

That way,

```
rsync -hxDPavilyzHFF --stats --delete ./ remote:/backup/
```

is the ideal backup command. The filtering is done by the -FF flags.

Note that using this method, you can have various .rsync-filter files in various subdirectories, applying to their respective subtrees. You can override exclusions in subdirectories as well, using this method.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync -a --include="/*/.*" --exclude="/.*" --exclude="node_modules" ./ ../out`
This is what worked for me, just make sure the input directory is the current directory to work.